# Javasciprt: Number - 0 returning NaN

Tags: javascript

I have an expression as

```
612 - Math.abs(16 - element.border ? parseInt(element.borderWidth) : 0)
```

where element.borderWidth can be any number string from 0-25 and element.border is a boolean but when element.border is false the expression

```
16 - element.border ? parseInt(element.borderWidth) : 0
```

is returning NaN, where element.borderWidth is NaN but the expression

```
element.border ? parseInt(element.borderWidth) : 0
```

should return 0 as border is false.

Edit:
The issue was that the ternary equation was not getting evaluated first so I just had to add parenthesis around it for it to get evaluated before the substration occured.

```
 612 - Math.abs(16 - (element.border ? parseInt(element.borderWidth) : 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If element.border is Boolean how do you expect to get any result from subtraction of number and Boolean (16-true/false). In addition if parseInt(element.borderWidth) returns 0 you have 0/0 which essentially returns NaN but parseint can return NaN as well if your trying to parse something different than number

Comment: element.border is a boolean and I'm not using that for subtraction it is used to check whether element.borderWidth is there or not, if element.border is false then the terneray equation will return 0 which leads to 16-0 otherwise if element.border is true then it will return element.borderWidth value and it will be 16 - element.borderWidth

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(Math.abs(16 - false ? parseInt("20") : 0))
>>20
console.log(Math.abs(16 - true ? parseInt("20") : 0))
>>20
console.log(16 - false)
>>16
console.log(16 - true)
>>15
console.log(16 - false ? parseInt(NaN) : 0)
>>NaN
console.log(false ? parseInt(NaN) : 0)
>>0
```

In your case value of the expression (16 - false) is 16 that's why you are getting the first value i.e. NaN

Comment: I will point out that (16 - false) is cast to a boolean before ?, so (16 - false) evaluates to **true**. (16 - true) is equal to 15 because true is cast to an integer, 1, so (16 - true) also evaluates to **true**.